# String comparisson differences between Mysql and Postgres - white spaces, special chars and case

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql

I'm building a Django application, and we decided to move from Mysql to Postgres. Now I'm facing a problem regarding string comparison.

In Mysql, 'Área de Assentamento ' equals to (=) 'Area de assentamento', for a `varchar(50)` with `utf8mb4_general_ci` encoding field.

The same does not apply Postgres.

The closer I've reached is using iexact with .strip(). However, for special chars it still misses.

I would like that

```
myvar = 'Área de Assentamento '
r = Myobject.objects.get(field__iexact=myvar.strip())
```

could return a matching result also in postgres for `field='Area de assentamento'`

Is there any way to achieve the same behavior from Mysql in Postgres?

Comment: I think you are looking for Unaccent... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/lookups/#std:fieldlookup-unaccent

Comment: Thanks! Just nothing that unaccent must come before iexact: r = Myobject.objects.get(field__unaccent__iexact=myvar.strip())